# Dijkstra without decrease key

Tags: graphs, shortest-path, heaps, priority-queues, dijkstras-algorithm

I was reading through [this paper, "Priority Queues and Dijkstra's Algorithm" by Mo Chen et al.](https://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/%7Erezaul/papers/TR-07-54.pdf), which suggests using Dijkstra's without edge relaxation, but to rather to just insert new nodes. Please see the pseudo code listed on the right-hand side below, which is taken from page 16 of that paper.

[image: Dijkstra's algorithm pseudocode from the paper]

But to me the code looks wrong. I think the comparison should be

```
k <= d[u]
```

and also the update of the d[u] in the next line seems redundant to me. I think the delete-min operation can never return a vertex with distance label k which is strictly less than d[u] since whenever a vertex distance pair is inserted into the priority queue the distance array d is updated. Am I correct in assuming that this is a mistake in the paper?

Answer (score 3):

You are right. Checking `k < d[u]` is not sufficient and updating `d[u]` on the next line is not necessary.

The check prevents proceeding when the source is picked up from the queue (then `k = 0` and `d[s] = 0`). Also, `d[u]` (`u` is fixed) is monotonically decreasing as loop proceeds, so even though it is updated after `(u, d[u])` is put on the queue, `k >= d[u]` holds when `(u,k)` is picked up from the queue. Moreover, if `d[u]` is strictly smaller than `k` , the element should simply be ignored since it cannot be the shortest path to `u`.

You can change the condition to `k == d[u]` and remove following update to `d[u]`.

Comment: I don’t think one should remove the if statement completely. If if one pulls a “dead” node out of the queue looping over its neighbors is unnecessary.

Comment: @user3726947 I wonder what node should be considered "dead." When minimum one is pulled from the queue, its `k` value is equal to `d[u]` so it seems worth visiting its neighbors.

Comment: I don’t think that’s true. Note that each time a better path to some vertex is found the vertex distance pair is inserted into the heap. Have a look at the algorithm on the right on page 16. So it might happen that a vertex has a worse distance than the optimal one recorded in the array d.

Comment: @user3726947 I got your point. The queue contains the "dead" entry, i.e. one whose distance value is greater than optimal distance in d. That happen after optimal one is pulled and d is updated. Remaining queue entries for the same vertex should be considered dead after minimum one is processed. So should the IF statement be `k == d[u]` removing the update on the next line?

Comment: I just updated the answer. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Wikipedia says "This can be done by additionally extracting the associated priority `p` from the queue and only processing further `if p < dist[u]`", but I think it should instead be `==` (maybe it was based on the typo from this paper?). Is that incorrect?

Comment: @Coder-256 Yes, I think so, too. Though I believe `==` is precise, many articles seem to prefer skipping non-equal cases by using `if dist[u] < p then continue;` probably because that is more intuitive and puts less burden on readers checking when the comparison becomes true.

Comment: @Ryoji Is there anything that can be done to amend the paper (considering that it was written in 2007)? As far as Wikipedia, I don't want to update it with my own word over an academic paper.

Comment: If we change the check to `if k == dist[u]`, then wouldn't we have to have already set `d[s] = 0` in the first step, before the `while` loop? Otherwise, we would dequeue the source from the priority queue and not do anything with it, because since `k` is 0 and `dist[s]` is ∞, it fails the check `if k == dist[u]`.